# Weird behavior of a MouseListener added to a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouselistener

I've hooked up a mouse listener to a JTable to call some stuff when mouse cursor leaves table's bounds. However, mouseExited() method is also called when the mouse cursor is leaving individual cells of a table. Is it some strange quirk in my code or a bug in Swing?

EDIT: I didn't mention that my table is a subclass of a JTable and not a standard JTable

Comment: Works fine for me with a standard JTable. Might be something with your class. Please post some code.

Comment: Works for me too... please post some code

Answer (score 1):

Sounds normal to me if you're not checking for `event.getSource() == myTable`

Answer (score 0):

Adding mouse listeners to PL&F-heavy components is not a great idea. They often have subcomponents which spoil the party. Mouse events are different from other events in that they bubble up the component hierarchy until they hit a component with a mouse listener (so adding a mouse listener is an intrusive operation). `JTable` in particular uses renderer to stamp each cell as well as editor components.

(Also subclass compnents such as `JTable`, or other classes such as `Thread`, is generally a bad idea.)

Comment: Mouse events can continue to propagate if a mouse listener doesn't consume it. And any specific reasons why you don't recommend extending `JTable`? I can understand why not `Thread`, but `JTable` has much stuff left out (e.g. search, hierarchy). You can add many features by extending table model, column model, header, etc., but I've run into cases where I have to extend JTable itself.

Comment: A listener doesn't have to call `consume()` to prevent the event bubbling up. Just the presence of a listener will do.